# @Cachable annotated method is not caching a new data after doing @CacheEvict

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

Developed an API to retrieve data from a table and put it into cache in spring boot from Eclipse. Integrated with an SAP cloud platform.

DB- SAP cloud HANA DB.

**Step-1:** Call an API from the postman.

**Step-2:** Method invoked. The method annotated with @Cacheable("dictionary")

** ** -->At this time the values from DB 4000+ records get cached
--> within 5 mins if postman executes, values are returning faster based on execution time as expected.

---

**Step-3:** Every 5 mins, @CacheEvict is scheduled.

** **Before Eviction starts, updating a DB column "comments" in DB** **

**Step-4:** Scheduled Eviction method executed.

```
@Service
public class CacheEvit {

    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;  

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/5 * * * ?") // execure after every 5 min
    public void clearCacheSchedule() {
        System.err.println("inside clear scheduled--" + cacheManager.getCacheNames());
        Cache c = cacheManager.getCache("dictionary");
        for (String name : cacheManager.getCacheNames()) {
            System.err.println("inside clear scheduled before clear in for loop" + cacheManager.getCacheNames()); 
            cacheManager.getCache("dictionary").clear(); // clear cache by name
        }

        if (c != null) {
            System.err.println("cleared succ -- " + cacheManager.getCacheNames());
        } else {
            System.err.println("cache is not null");
        }
    }

}
```

```
 @Cacheable("dictionary")
  public List<DictionaryEntity> getDictionaryData() {
      System.err.println("inside getDictionaryData");
    return dictionaryServiceImpl.getDictionary();
  }
```

@EnableScheduling
@EnableCaching --> declared in Starter class.

```
@Bean
  public CacheManager cacheManager() {
      SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
      cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(
        new ConcurrentMapCache("dictionary")));
      return cacheManager;
  }
```

These both are in different java classes and different services.

**Problem:** As cache got cleared, The method with @Cachable is executed ( observed by printing log ) **but the value of cache is not loaded newly as we edited comments, still its returning old values**

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that the cacheable method was in the same class, which you mentioned are not in your case. However, cacheable will not get called if the classes are part of the same bean. I separated them and it works fine for me. Hope it helps.